# Pip errors after upgrading

Tags: pip, importerror, traceback

After upgrading to pip 18.1 whenever I try to do anything with pip I get this import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (C:\Users\asbwi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Uninstall pip and reinstall it again, It looks like you broke the pip

Comment: I tried that, still no luck

Comment: uninstall pip and delete pip folder and install either pip 8 or pip 10.

Answer (score 1):

1. **pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools --user**

   ```
   This should solve your issue with pip

                    or
   ```
2. **python -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3** [ This will downgrade the pip version ]

   ```
   Check the pip version using "**pip --version**"
   ```